# Using animated PNGS in mobile app

Tags: android, animation, apng

I'm creating a mobile app using html, css and jquery and packaging through phonegap. some parts of the app require animations, I decided to do this through gifs as what I wanted was too hard to animate through css. However the quality of gifs with transparency is terrible, (looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZmYi.jpg) so I tried to use aPNGS, but they did not work when i tried the APK file on the phone (still not supported?) is there a way to get aPNGS to work on an app? or another alternative? i have tried gifs, sprite sheets, webp and webm but nothing compares to the quality of pngs.

Comment: APNGs are not yet supported by Android, without the use of 3rd party libraries. But you can take advantage of Android animations. That is, a number of regular PNGs played in sequence.

Comment: Losless webp should have the same quality as APNG.